# How to move my ev3 robot a certain distance and get it to stop?

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I'm starting out with an EV3 lego robot and my first project to pop the cherry was getting it to move a certain distance, and having it stop when the ultrasonic sensor dectects something 3 cm away. But I have tried so many things and can't get it to work right. here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ev3dev2.motor import MoveTank, OUTPUT_B, OUTPUT_C, seconds
from ev3dev2.sensor.lego import TouchSensor
from ev3dev2.sensor.lego import UltrasonicSensor
from time import sleep
from time import seconds


us = UltrasonicSensor()
tank_pair = MoveTank(OUTPUT_B, OUTPUT_C, seconds)


tank_pair.on(left_speed=30, right_speed=30)

if distance_centimeters(10):  
    tank_pair.off()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to move the tank without the sensor stuff?  So are you asking how to implement `distance_centimeters`?

Comment: That and getting it to move a set distance.

Comment: To get it to move a set distance, you will have to calibrate, doing repeated measurements to learn how far it travels per second when the speed is set to 30.  If you know how many revolutions per minute that is, and you know the circumference of the tire, you can compute it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this:

```
import time
...
while us.distance_centimeters() > 10.0:
    time.sleep( 0.1 )
  
tank_pair.off()
```